# How to save image loaded through url into sqlite database has a binary format

Tags: android

friend's,
   I need to know how to save image loading through url has a original image in sqlite database.how can i convert image url into binary format and to retrieve original image from database.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you want to store the image in the database? Can't you just store it on the FS and store the location to the file in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
getContentResolver().openOutputStream()
```

For more information look at:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

An example at: https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html

Comment: i'm doing it so when the device is in offline,i have to access the contents from database,and this content also have image,thats why i'm doing it. i followed link you have given above,i converted the image and stored in database,but when i get back for db i'm getting nullpointer exception,actually i have table field for image has blob,and i am getting couldn't typecast blob to string..how can i solve this issue.

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without you supplying any code ;)